# XCOPY Command Works in Windows XP Batch File, but not in Windows 7 Pro Batch File

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I have the following xcopy command which runs perfectly under Windows XP, but will not work properly under Windows 7 Pro.

```
xcopy "c:\Data Files\Dave's Data\*.*"   "m:\Dave's Data"   /R/D /E/H
```

The batch file command runs perfectly the very first time - when the destination (*m:\Dave's Data*) is empty.  However, when the batch file is run the second time, the destination directory tree has been created and exists.  While it works in subsequent runs in Windows XP, it does not in Win 7 Pro.  I do not understand what xcopy is doing, but it seems to be trying to recreate (at least on a temporary basis) the destination directory tree on m:\Dave's Data   When the destination directory exists on *m:\Dave's Data*, the `xcopy` command fails in Windows 7.

I have a cmd.exe icon on my Windows 7 desktop set to run with administrator privileges.  I am the only user on the PC and have administrator privileges.  I have found that if I type the `xcopy` command exactly into the cmd.exe window (no batch file), the `xcopy` command runs perfectly the first time and all subsequent times on Windows 7.

This leads me to believe that in Windows 7, there is an issue with administrator privileges when executing the `xcopy` command within a batch file.

I'd appreciate any suggestions to get xcopy working in Windows 7.

Comment: What is the name of the batch file?

Comment: Aren't you missing a backslash in your source path? `c:\Data Files\Dave's Data\*.*"`  I would also put one at the end of your destination path. `"m:\Dave's Data\"`

Comment: Squashman is absolutely correct.  The source should have the trailing \     "c:\Data Files\Dave's Data\*.*"    The " " were necessary in my version of XP when names had space characters.  Sorry for the typo.  However, the end of the destination path does not get a \ as the contents of the destination " " are the destination directory.

Comment: Having a trailing slash at the end tells XCOPY that it is definitely copying to a directory and not a file.  It does not hurt to have it there and has always been a best practice for me when using XCOPY.

Comment: My experience is that a trailing destination backslash allows for the destination directory to be created if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: There is the switch `/I` which tells the `xcopy` command that the target is a directory... Anyway, I'm sorry, I can't reproduce the issue...

Comment: I really don't know what to say here except that the command as I typed it in worked perfectly in Windows XP.  I did not use a trailing \ in the destination.  Subsequent runs of the batch file created new directories if the source had one and did not if the source did not.  But, the real issue of my posting is to discover why the xcopy command does not work in a batch file in Windows 7 Professional.  If anyone has any insight here, I'd sure appreciate the help.